# Access Dropbox Metrics via Powershell

Tags: powershell, dropbox, dropbox-api

I would like to access Dropbox metrics similar to what is available on the Dropbox Admin Console such as storage information and shared folder counts.  The Dropbox API provides rich access to considerable amount of information, so how I can get to this information via Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

The API will provide many days of information about metrics.  The example below uses the 1.0 API, which is being replaced by version 2.0 shortly.  For documentation about the API please go to Dropbox.com/developer

This example generates the most current storage and shared folder metric.

Sample output:

04/27/2016 00:00:00,6220390,2163

```
# Prompt or hard-code  for Team Member Management permission 
# the Token is obtained from Dropbox website - the Admin Console
#$token = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your Dropbox Business API App token (Team Member Management permission): " 
$token = "Bearer KXasdflkjasfoivXnasdliefdslksafToivU932432489432" 

$object = New-Object psobject 

# Make API call 
$teamstats = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://api.dropbox.com/1/team/reports/get_storage -Body (ConvertTo-Json $object) -ContentType application/json -Headers @{ 
            Authorization = $token } -Method Post 

# API returns 1 startdate only, which is the day before the data actually begins 
$startdate = [datetime]$teamstats.start_date

#API returns in an array various elements such as storage consumed & number of shared folders
#below I convert them to an array with a simpler name
$StorageArray = $teamstats.total_usage
$ShareArray = $teamstats.shared_folders

# of entries in the array
$MaxCount = $storagearray.length

# I am only interested in the last entry (most current)
$LastEntry = $MaxCount - 1

#adjust the date so it reflects the right time period
$ts = New-TimeSpan -Days $lastentry
$startdate = $startdate + $ts

#grab the last entry for storage and shares
$storage = $StorageArray[$LastEntry]
$Shares = $ShareArray[$LastEntry]

#I load this data into other software, which cannot deal with storage in Bytes
#when the number is so large (terabytes)
#so I convert it to megabytes
[long]$intNum = $Storage -as [long]
$intnum = $intnum / (1024 * 1024) # convert to mb

"$startdate,$intnum,$Shares"

Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."

$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```